# Why do i get this error in node.js - solidity?

Tags: javascript, solidity

im trying to connect to a smart contract with web3 but i keep getting this error

first i do

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3('mainnet.infura....')
var abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_customerAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"dividendsOf","outputs":....]
var contractAddress = '0x123456789'
```

now when i run

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)
```

I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Contract' of undefined

but why is contract undefined??

Im using node in ubuntu18.04

when i just run the variables i get the correct result, so the variables are working...

Comment: The error doesn't mean that `Contract` is undefined. it means `new web3.eth` returns undefined and can't read `Contract` property of undefined object.

Comment: ok, so what do i do?

Comment: You might check if `new web3` works correctly.

Comment: i see no error- seems im connected to infura

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(web3)`?

Comment: a bunch of post: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_post' },
     unsubscribe: 
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'shh_unsubscribe' } },
  bzz: 
   Bzz {
     givenProvider: null,
     currentProvider: null,
     isAvailable: [Function],
     upload: [Function],
    
But i made it work, i started over again with declaring variables and using infura- i think the mistake was that i used mainnet.infura insteed of https://mainnet.infura

Comment: it needs the https when using infura- its working now-- thanks everyone